# Twitter button not displaying tweet count in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter

I noticed that the twitter button is not displaying the tweet count in chrome (not even in their [own developers page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)).

Does anybody have any idea what the problem is and if there's a way to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It works perfectly for me https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet, in the page you mention they explicitly add `data-count="none"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me, try opening a new private window (Ctrl + Shift + N).

Sometimes the chrome plugins brakes some pages, for example the adBlocker plugin

Comment: Confirmed, AdBlock is hiding the counter for me too :)

Comment: it's ok! it's ok! don't call me god!

Comment: Thanks, you're right, it was the AdBlock. Thank you very much!